# Setting the background of ImageView through java

Tags: java, android

Basically I want to set the background of an imageview to a jpg I have located in my drawable folder. How would I do this?

```
public void changer(int a){
    Ryan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(a == 1){
        Ryan.setBackground(@drawable/awkward_frog).

    }
}
```

Thank you, I hope i was clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use **setImageResource** function like this :

```
Ryan.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_frog);
```

Comment: Well, it hasn't given me any errors yet, but I haven't finished my code! Thanks, gonna approve when done

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is very basic and already has solutions.

**Solution 1 :**

This will occupy only the size of the image in ImageView. Rest will be filled by background.

```
public void changer(int a){
Ryan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(a == 1){
 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_frog);
}

if(a == 2){
 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.awkward_cat);
}

}
```

**Solution 2**

This will fit the image for the entire background. Means it will stretch the image to fill the background completely even if the image height:width is too small.

```
public void changer(int a){
Ryan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(a == 1){
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.awkward_frog);
}

if(a == 2){
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.awkward_cat);
}

}
```

**NOTE :** The question you asked already has answers, improve your search skills. Because same type of question available in the Stackoverflow will be marked as duplicate.